# setting transparency to buttons in android

Tags: android, button

I want to make Buttons with different transparency levels in android.I have used `"@android:color/transparent"`. But it makes the button 100% transparent. I need a 70% transparent button. Here is the XML code that I am working on:

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center" 
    android:layout_weight="1">

    <Button android:id="@+id/one" 
        android:text="@string/dtmf_1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:textColor="@color/white" ></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/two"  
        android:text="@string/dtmf_2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:textColor="@color/white" ></Button>
    <Button android:id="@+id/three" 
        android:text="@string/dtmf_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"  
        android:textColor="@color/white" ></Button>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Using XML**

If you want to set color and along with that if you want to set transparent then you have to use that color code .

```
android:color="#66FF0000"    // Partially transparent red
android:alpha="0.25"         // 25% transparent
```

**Using java**

And if you want to set dynamically (java code)then try this,

```
myButton.getBackground().setAlpha(64);  // 25% transparent
```

- i.e .INT ranges from 0 (fully transparent) to 255 (fully opaque)

Comment: However, calling `setAlpha()` on `View` expects a value between 0 and 1:


`myButton.setAlpha(0.5)`

Comment: This would set background transparency of button.  But not text transparency of button.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky This also affects text transparency of button.

Answer (score 9):

You can define your own "transparent" color in styles.xml and play with the alfa of the color, for example:

```
<color name="Transparent">#00000000</color>
<color name="Transparent80">#80000000</color>
```

EDIT: second one is 50% transparency

Comment: I thought #7F000000 was 50% :)

Answer (score 7):

Use this code in your background color

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 6):

Try `android:background="#70FF0000"` in your button code. Works for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can set a background for the button,then achieve the transparency by adjusting the alpha attribute of the button,

```
android:alpha="0.7"
```

Makes the opacity 70 percent.

Answer (score 5):

To set the background of button as transparent do:

```
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Comment: OP needs a 70% transparent button. Did You read the question?

Answer (score 2):

try adding this to your **button**  `android:color="#55000000""`

```
<Button android:id="@+id/three" android:text="@string/dtmf_3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" 
        android:color="#55000000" <!--Here--!>
        android:textColor="@color/white" ></Button>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try setting

```
android:alpha="0.7"
```

property on your Button in xml layout file

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this:

```
android:color="#66FF0000"    // Partially transparent red
android:alpha="0.25"         // 25% transparent
```

you can use this:

`android:background="#00FFFFFF"`

Answer (score 1):

You can set transparency with color. In Android color is broken into 4 8-bit (0-255) segments, with the first 8-bit (0-255) controlling the alpha.  For example with the basic color code for Light Gray: D3D3D3.  If I want light grey transparent, add 0 and to light grey and get 0D3d3d3 for 100% transparent, or 227(E3 in hex) and get E3D3D3D3 for 50% or 255(FF in Hex) and get FFD3D3D3 for 0%

Answer (score 1):

For creating a button transparent with dark grey as border with the text to be visible too.

1. Create a new empty drawable file and named it: button_transparent.xml

Copy Paste the below code into it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<corners android:radius="20dp" />
<gradient
    android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
    android:startColor="@android:color/transparent" />
<stroke
    android:width="2dp"
    android:color="@color/grey" /> <!-- color name="grey">#5b5b5b</color> -->

</shape>
```

2. Now into your yourActivityName.xml, paste the following code:

   ```
   <Button
    android:layout_width="@dimen/dp_120"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/dp_35"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_transparent"
    android:text="Edit profile"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/grey"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
   ```

That's all you need to do. Your button will look like this :
[image]

Comment: For some reason, I still have the border color as the original of how it was.

Comment: Now it works, I accepted your edit. Thanks mate

Comment: No Problem, this actually helped me on what I was doing, so I respect that.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `android:alpha` property for button will help...
Set the colour you want and then set the alpha property.

```
android:color="#e5e5e5"    
android:alpha="0.25"
```

**0.25** means **25%**

Answer (score -1):

Just Use `'@null'` to background of button makes transparency in button

```
android:background="@null"
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. Is there something missing?